# allegro 5.1.3 and microsoft visual studio 2010 for android?

Tags: visual-c++, android-ndk, allegro, visual-studio-2010, allegro5

Ive set up allegro and msv2010 on my laptop and ive set up android dev with msvc2010.  However I cant figure out how to set up a project for the new allegro android dev. i have set up the and android sdk, java jdk, ndk and all the rest.

http://vs-android.googlecode.com/files/vs-android_samples.zip i can compile these android projects in msvc2010 and can create standard allegro projects.

I was just wondering does anyone know how to create an android project with allegro in msvc2010 or do you know where i can find the instructions on how to do so.

Thanking You

Comment: You'll probably be better off asking at http://www.allegro.cc, and if you get a good answer copying it here. The Android port works, but it's alpha and probably will require you to work with some of the Allegro devs.

Answer (score 0):

Platforms supported by allegro 5.0 :

Unix/Linux,
Windows (MSVC, MinGW),
MacOS X,
iPhone.

Allegro 5.1 also adds support for:

Android.

so I think we can't do that till today (12/2/2013).

thank you.

source:
http://alleg.sourceforge.net/readme.html